# Give FTP user access to a particular directory

Tags: centos7, ftp

In my centOS 7 server I have created a user using following

```
useradd -d /var/www/html/stage -s /bin/bash user1
```

I would like to give only stage folder access to user1. Now when I connect to my server using FTP with the user1, the default directory that shows, in the beginning, is stage only but the user is also able to go back to root server directories.
Plz, suggest what changes should I make so that my user is only able to access the stage directory.

I have followed a tutorial,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A1czbNwd2R4

Basic steps mentioned in the tutorial.[image]

But this is not working for me. Plz guide me in the right direction to create a user and give specific directory access to it.

I have also made the changes in vsftpd.conf file located in /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and restarted vsftpd using systemctl restart vsftpd.service

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

But still my user is able to access directories oher than stage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need implement chroot for your ftp user if you want your sftp also have chroot you need implement it please follow step :

```
vi /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
```

uncommented line , Make sure it exist

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Save file and exit and Restart vsftpd:

```
/etc/init.d/vsftpd restart
```

note : all your ftp user will be limited to their home directory

Comment: I have updated my question with the changes you suggested but still I am able to access other directories using that user. Anything else I shall look for.

Comment: Dear alternative is config chroot directory and chroot user in your ftp configuration, i tested this solution in my ftp : https://sharadchhetri.com/how-to-install-and-configure-ftp-server-with-chroot-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/    https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-centos-7/

Comment: Thanks for the link, will create new user according to it.

Comment: @RajeevSingh anytime